# Redis performance with 100,000 writes

Tags: php, performance, redis

According to Redis documentation:

`Remember that with commodity hardware Redis is able to handle 100.000 writes per second. That's enough even for Twitter, I guess.`

My PC configuration is:

CPU: Ci7 1.5GHz
RAM: 4GB. never goes to max usage!!
OS: Win7

on my localhost, I tested 100.000 `SADD` OR `set` with this script in PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
    Redis::set( 'log:'.$i, $i );
}
```

But this takes `30 seconds` to finish. Why?!

Comment: Possibly because your use of static calls is going to have to make a new connection to redis for every call to set(): you'll get a lot better performance if you instantiate the class, then call set(), because the connection will only be done once. This is especially important if you're connecting to a redis server by name rather than by IP address

Comment: though you don't even indicate which redis interface for PHP you're using: PHPredis or predis?

Comment: I am using Laravel's built-in Redis driver. I think it uses Predis.

Comment: Because you use a single connection and do not pipeline anything. Please read http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: Can I pipeline on a single server ?

Comment: predis supports command pipelining on both single and aggregate connections.... whether Laravel's Redis wrapper provides a method to take advantage of that is another matter

Comment: even without pipeline, it should not take 30 seconds. there are some benchmarks without pipeline that do 30.000 sets per seconds. in my case it is 3.000.

Comment: use phpredis. read http://alekseykorzun.com/post/53283070010/benchmarking-memcached-and-redis-clients and http://www.clorophilla.net/blog/?p=499

Comment: did you change anything in the config file, or do you use the default conf? if you increased the frequency of disk writings it would explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to put it here...

```
Redis::pipeline(function($pipe)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
    {
        $pipe->set("key:$i", $i);
    }
});
```